# htacces friendly links not working properly

Tags: .htaccess

i would like to add a friendly link to subpage ?id=22, but something go wrong, when I go to links, it takes me an error , page not found on this server. What im doing wrong ?

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=22$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.mywebsite.pl/night-concert/? [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for answers.